# create dynamic widgets from JSON in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create dynamic widgets from JSON getting from API.
I just follow the blog https://medium.com/@limonadev/rendering-flutter-widgets-from-json-easily-3db02490519e
But after doing all the stuff we are getting some error
"/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_dynamic_widget-1.4.1/lib/src/builders/json_scaffold_builder.dart:246:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'."
My main.dart file is:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:json_dynamic_widget/json_dynamic_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Simple Example',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: DynamicText());
  }
}

class DynamicText extends StatefulWidget {
  final url = 'https://medium-json-dynamic-widget.herokuapp.com/mainpage';

  @override
  _DynamicTextState createState() => _DynamicTextState();
}

class _DynamicTextState extends State<DynamicText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var widgetJson = json.decode(snapshot.data.body);
          var widget = JsonWidgetData.fromDynamic(
            widgetJson,
          );
          return widget.build(context: context);
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      future: _getWidget(),
    );
  }

  Future<http.Response> _getWidget() async {
    return http.get(widget.url);
  }
}


class SimpleText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Static Widget'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('This is a very important message!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and pubspec.yaml file is:

```
 name: json_to_v
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.12.2
  json_dynamic_widget: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

if I upgrade **json_dynamic_widget: ^1.0.3 to ^2.1.0**
We get following error:

Because json_dynamic_widget >=2.0.0 <2.1.0 depends on json_schema2 ^2.0.0 and json_schema2 >=2.0.0 <=2.0.0 depends on rest_client ^2.0.0, json_dynamic_widget >=2.0.0 <2.1.0 requires rest_client ^2.0.0 or json_schema2 ^2.0.0+1.
And because json_dynamic_widget >=2.1.0 depends on json_schema2 ^2.0.0+1, json_dynamic_widget >=2.0.0 requires rest_client ^2.0.0 or json_schema2 ^2.0.0+1.
And because json_schema2 >=2.0.0+1 depends on rest_client ^2.0.1+1 which depends on http ^0.13.0, json_dynamic_widget >=2.0.0 requires http ^0.13.0.
So, because json_to_v depends on both http ^0.12.2 and json_dynamic_widget ^2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because json_to_v depends on both http ^0.12.2 and json_dynamic_widget ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)

And If we comment below the line and related code then the error has gone.

```
import 'package:json_dynamic_widget/json_dynamic_widget.dart';
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your **pubspec.yaml**:

`http: ^0.13.3`

`json_dynamic_widget: ^3.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but still not working..